# How to use kiosk mode in opera Version:32.0.1948.69?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, opera, kiosk-mode

i want to use opera for a web based application that needs to run in kiosk mode and i tried chrome but some features like npapi plugin is disabled in chome that's why i need to run my web-based app on opera but i am finding difficult to run opera in kiosk mode,i tried /kioskmode, -kioskmode, /k in shortcut of opera("C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe" /KioskMode)  but it's not working for me.Am i doing something wrong? According to their link http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/kiosk.html This should work right?

Comment: The "12.10" suggests to me that might be the pre-rewrite Opera, which had an entirely different feature set from the current versions.

Comment: thank you for replying,i installed older version but browser does not load my app page properly so i have to use latest version...

Comment: 12.10 version also not opening opera in kiosk mode when /kioskmode switch is applied :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js). Near nwjs.exe create package.json with next options:

```
{
  "main": "<web app url>",
  "name": "kiosk example",
  "description": "kiosk example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "frame": false,
    "resizable": false,
    "show": true,
    "kiosk": true,
    "title": "kiosk example"
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  },
  "chromium-args": "--force-gpu-rasterization"
}
```

Also, I recommend you to create kiosk user and set *nwjs.exe* as shell for this user. Windows 7 and early:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\nwjs.exe>"
```

Windows 8 and later:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\nwjs.exe>"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,i didn't know about nwjs before now i have to learn about it

Comment: Welcome ) Also, feel free ask any questions in nwjs gitter chat: https://gitter.im/nwjs/nw.js

Comment: Thanks a million!! @VoidVolker for introducing me to nwjs.But now I am finding hard to run exe in nwjs  will you please help me out.In opera i was using meadco-neptune plugin to run exe but it won't work in nwjs,I saw your gitter chats and from it I created plugin folder in root of my app and paste npmeadax.dll file in it still nwjs browser showing plugin could not be loaded also i have package.jason file as you told me in your above answer,Thank you in advance

Comment: var child_process = require('child_process')
    , exec = child_process.exec
    , execSync = child_process.execSync
    , execFile = child_process.execFile
    , execFileSync = child_process.execFileSync
;

exec('my_programm.exe');